# How to use regex in javascript which is saved in the database and retrieved as string?

Tags: javascript, regex

I have a requirement to keep regex expressions in the database and use them in the application based on different conditions.

Normally the following script works.

For example:

```js
    let str: string = "C:\MyFolder\SubFolder";

    // When using regex in following way, it works
    var regex1 = new RegExp(/^[a-zA-Z]:\\((((?![<>:"/\\|?*]).)+((?<![ .])\\)?)*$)/g);

    if (regex1.test(str)) {
        console.log("Valid");
    } else {
        console.log("Invalid");
    }
    
    // Output: Valid
```

But when the same code is modified to use regex from the database it doesn't work.

```js
let str: string = "C:\MyFolder\SubFolder";

    // When using regex in following way, it doesn't work
    var regex1 = new RegExp(regexFromDB);

    if (regex1.test(str)) {
        console.log("Valid");
    } else {
        console.log("Invalid");
    }
    
    // Here regexFromDB = "/^[a-zA-Z]:\\((((?![<>:"/\\|?*]).)+((?<![ .])\\)?)*$)/g"
    
    // Output: Invalid
```

I even tried to replace the double quotes from the `regexFromDB` but it didn't work.

Can someone suggest me the right way to use regex from database while keeping the basic requirement of re-usability intact. Thanks

Comment: No need to pass a regex literal to `new RegExp` - just use the regex literal itself. When you have a string to turn into a regex, as in the second code, double-escape the backslashes.

Comment: BTW, it should be `let str: string = "C:\\MyFolder\\SubFolder";`

Comment: I tried to replace every single backslash with double backslashes but it makes the string invalid.

var regex2 = new RegExp("/^[a-zA-Z]:\\\\((((?![<>:"/\\\\|?*]).)+((?<![ .])\\\\)?)*$)/g");

Seems like I need to disable special meaning for other characters at-least in my case. Can you just give me some idea so I can continue such changes with other regex strings.